# Exporting the output of MATLAB's methodsview

Tags: matlab, api, com, export, matlab-figure

MATLAB's [`methodsview`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/methodsview.html) tool is handy when exploring the API provided by external classes (Java, COM, etc.). Below is an example of how this function works:

```
myApp = actxserver('Excel.Application');
methodsview(myApp)
```

[image: Example output of methodsview for]

I want to keep the information in this window for future reference, by exporting it to a table, a `cell` array of strings, a `.csv` or another similar format, preferably without using external tools.

#### Some things I tried:

- This window allows selecting one line at a time and doing "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>" on it, which results in a tab-separated text that looks like this:

  ```
   Variant GetCustomListContents   (handle, int32)
  ```

  Such a strategy can work when there are only several methods, but not viable for (the usually-encountered) long lists.
- I could not find a way to access the table data via the figure handle (w/o using external tools like [`findjobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) or [`uiinspect`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17935-uiinspect-display-methods--properties---callbacks-of-an-object)), as `findall(0,'Type','Figure')` "do not see" the `methodsview` window/figure at all.

My MATLAB version is R2015a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, `methodsview.m` file is accessible and allows to get some insight on how the function works. Inside is the following comment:

> ```
> %// Internal use only: option is optional and if present and equal to
> %// 'noUI' this function returns methods information without displaying 
> %// the table. `
> ```

After some trial and error, I saw that the following works:

```
[titles,data] = methodsview(myApp,'noui');
```

... and returns two arrays of type `java.lang.String[][]`.

From there I found a couple of ways to present the data in a meaningful way:

- Table:

  ```
  dataTable = cell2table(cell(data));
  dataTable.Properties.VariableNames = matlab.lang.makeValidName(cell(titles));
  ```

  [image: Output as a table...]
- Cell array:

  ```
  dataCell = [cell(titles).'; cell(data)];
  ```

Important note: In the table case, the "`Return Type`" column title gets renamed to `ReturnType`, since table titles have to be valid MATLAB identifiers, [as mentioned in the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2table.html#input_argument_namevalue_variablenames).